# Mesa installation - Make process - Issue

Tags: opengl, mesa

I am trying to build and install MESA library in ubuntu 13.10..

In the make command, I am facing the following erros..

```
sathish@ubuntu:~/Desktop/layer_management-1_2/work/mesa/src/loader$ make -j 4
 cd ../.. && /bin/bash ./config.status src/loader/Makefile depfiles
config.status: creating src/loader/Makefile
config.status: executing depfiles commands
  CC       libloader_la-loader.lo
../../libtool: line 444: $'\r': command not found
../../libtool: line 447: $'\r': command not found
../../libtool: line 452: $'\r': command not found
../../libtool: line 473: $'\r': command not found
../../libtool: line 523: $'\r': command not found
../../libtool: line 529: $'\r': command not found
../../libtool: line 539: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
'./../libtool: line 539: `  case `(set -o) 2>/dev/null` in *posix*) set -o posix;; esac
make: *** [libloader_la-loader.lo] Error 2
```

Can anybody point the cause of this error.

Answer (score 1):

You can just see this one: http://hc0510.blog.51cto.com/537035/116070
It's the problem of '\r' in unix, just delete them.